# Bug Hibernate OneToMany/ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make a relationship using OneToMany and ManyToOne, but when I try to insert a record into database without add a object(class) in the list OneToMany, the hibernate try to insert the record OneToMany anyway. Example:
Employee Class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<Shift>();
}
```

Shift Class:

```
@Entity
public class Shift implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

When I try to insert the record:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
entityManager.persist(employee);
entityManager.flush();
```

How can I fix it? I'm using SQL Server Database.

```
14:53:49,660 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Hibernate: insert into Employee
14:53:49,762 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Hibernate: insert into Shift(EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding,It is because of you have specified `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`in the `Employee` class.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<Shift>();
```

Which means,when you will make any operation on `Employee` object,it will cascade it to `Shift` class too,due to this.

For ref see here :- [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)

Comment: What do you advise? Because the Hibernate is returning problem with null value in EMPLOYEE_ID column, and the size of the list is 0 because I didn't add a Shift object, and when I add one Shift Object, the hibernate try to insert two records in the table Shift instead one.

Comment: It should not make null value for EMPLOYEE_ID column in Shift table. regarding your second point,please post your code herr(update your question)